# Only My Computer Won't Connect to a Specific IP

Tags: windows-7, dns

I'm having issues connecting to our Web Server IP from my computer. This seems to be isolated to my computer as I'm able to access it from every other machine I attempt just fine. By not connect, I mean that in a browser, I get "This webpage is not available", in putty, it just hangs. If I log into any other machine whether local or external, everything works as expected.

I've restarted my computer, flushed caches, and flushed DNS, and disabled Firewalls. The issue started after the most recent Windows updates though I don't know that it's related.

This is not a hosts file issue either. I've cleared the file and got the same results. Regardless, even attempting the IP directly, I don't get anywhere.

This has even stumped our IT company. I really don't want to have to reinstall Windows and my earliest restore point is after the issue started. I'd really appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: Have you tried changing IP address of that machine? Or move it into another network?

Comment: how about ping ?

Comment: wireshark is a good idea too

Comment: I have not tried changing the IP of the web server. That would be a pretty big deal as it is a production web server. Pings fail but this machine doesn't respond to pings anyway.

Comment: I haven't used wireshark since my college days. I'll see how far I can get with that. Thanks all for the input so far.

Comment: Temporarily disable your windows firewall and see if that solves it.

Answer (score -1):

Check the cable. Make sure the LEDs are blinking when there is activity.

Install `telnet` via the [instructions here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) Alternatively, download `nmap`. Your'e going to use that tool to try to connect to the web-server:

```
telnet 193.52.1.6 80
```

(or whatever the IP is, but keep the `80`). If it hangs, check the Windows Firewall and disable it completely. It will complain. Do it anyway. Try again. If it still hangs, it's not the firewall and you should re-enable it. Go to next step.

Next step: Get a packet-sniffer. The best option is to run it on the **server** if possible. The options for unix include `tcpdump`, `wireshark`. `wireshark` also runs on Windows. Get them to listen for all packets coming from your IP address.  If you can't run it on the server, put another host on your network -- the same LAN -- any PC with Windows or Linux will do, and run it there. Tell your PC to connect to this new host (using telnet, nmap, or the browser). If you're not getting anything at all, we have to go down to very basics -- it might be a bad port on the hub/router of your network. Check that connection to, change ports, cables.

If you get it to your LAN's host but not to the server, it's possibly a router or firewall problem. You'll need your packet sniffer further on down the line to know what's going on. Are the packets reaching their destination? Are they getting responses? Does the session start and then stall?

My bet is: bad port on the hub/switch/drop.

Comment: -1  he said he tried putty , he wrote "in putty, it just hangs".  And you are lecturing him about what telnet is.. and also you tell him it's an advanced service.. "advanced" is an adjective you decided to add, not a technical term. And he shouldn't really have to install the telnet service ideally - if he only wants to use the client, and telnet service is generally not recommended as people tend to use ssh for more security and automatic logon and other proxying and forwarding features.

Comment: You write " The common unix tools include ...wireshark"    <-- Wireshark formerly Ethereal, and like ethereal, is cross-platform  it runs on Windows not just *nix and maybe even also ran on Windows when it was written or produced. I use wireshark and years ago, ethereal. Re tcpdump, indeed  tcpdump is A *nix tool though it has windows ports(and technically what he'd use is a 3rd party tool for windows).   Also, you write "hub/switch/drop"  strange to see the word drop among hub/switch with a slash like that. Perhaps you mean packets dropping at the hub/switch?

Comment: "Check the cable. Make sure the LEDs are blinking when there is activity."

The OP can reach other machines. His network cable is properly connected.

Comment: @Hennes it's not clear to me his networking is fine. Perhaps you should refrain from downvoting me because you interpret his response differently. He writes "If I log into any other machine whether local or external, everything works as expected" but that doesn't mean it's at the same time as he's having the issues. You cannot make such assumptions in odd cases like these.

Comment: @barlop (1) telnet *client* is not always installed on Windows. It's an add-on package you install as part of advanced services. (2) When was the last time you tried to use putty to connect to an HTTP service via the telnet option? Unless you know what's going on, its confusing as f.k. (3) just because i describe wireshark as a "unix tool" doesn't mean it's not also a windows tool. What's wong with you? Why are you picking on my semantics? What's your f'in point? (4) A "drop" in networking terms is a place where an ethernet jack is fitted to the wall like an ordinary electrical outlet.

Comment: @Otheus thank you for your help. These guys are right though. The only place there is an issue is connecting from my machine to that one server. My computer can connect to anything else and anything else, even computers within my lan, can connect to the server. As mentioned, I've disabled all firewalls for testing.

Comment: Can the server connect to your machine? And what about ping?

Comment: @Otheus u use the phrase "advanced services". When I google "Windows 7" "advanced services"   the first link is about SQL, the second is about SQL, the third is about "advanced text services".  I don't see what you are talking about.  The option for telnet I see in "programs and features,turn windows features on and off", I see u can tick telnet client n u can click telnet server.n no doubt it's listed in the services.msc window. But I do not see the term "advanced services" used.Is it an MS term,or just a term you used? (btw,I used nc just now to http2 127.0.0.1 GET / HTTP/1.0<ENTER><ENTER>)

Comment: and why are you saying putty is confusing to use for the test, while saying to use telnet for the test.. the technical usage is pretty much the same. `putty w.x.y.z 80` `telnet w.x.y.z 80`  `nc w.x.y.z 80`  I will remove the -1 I gave you 'cos you at least put forth an argument.

Comment: @barlop Because, putty is trying to do SSH always, no matter which port you use, so you can't use HTTP commands to verify anything, unlike with telnet. Further, when you run putty to try to connect to a host, you don't know if it succeeds or fails -- you'll just get a blank window until putty times out. But if it connects succesfully, you get a blank window, and you don't know for a minute whether it is hung nor why.

Comment: @barlop re telnet client. I faultily recall that the telnet client was bundled with Windows NT "advanced services" CD/DVD... we're talking late 90s. 
For the OP, here's how to install it on Win 7: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/telnet-faq#1TC=windows-7

Comment: @barlop Where do you get NC for windows? I'm on Win7, I don't have it.

Comment: A)Putty GUI has more options than the command line, you can choose Raw or SSH. Putty command line is a bit rubbish,,a version of putty on one comp I was using seems to do raw but a later one seems not to, and as you suggest,might do ssh.. one thing putty command line can do is load profiles that were saved in the gui,and the profiles can have specific settings - in that it is flexible B)nc is with cygwin.If u haven't heard of cygwin then download it and fall in love with the *nix tools and bash shell ported to windows. You might want to check out gnuwin32 too though gnuwin32 doesn't include nc