# Issuing GET command from Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

I was reading a question about finding the ip address of a website.  One of the answers said to issue: "GET / HTTP.1.1" followed by: "host:website.port" to find a specific page.  My question is how and where do I enter commands like that in Windows 8.1.  Command prompt did not do the trick.  Thanks

Comment: Where did you read this question to which to refer? What OS was it talking about? "Get" is not really a command in any OS, at least not in an HTTP context.  It's how you request stuff from a web server using a client of some kind (web client, telnet, etc.).  Looks to me like you missed a step. I'd be more specific, but again, I have no idea what question/answer you're referring to, so we have no context to base better/actual answers.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007  probably he misunderstood what was going on in this rather recent question  http://superuser.com/questions/912102/only-my-computer-wont-connect-to-a-specific-ip/912117#comment1227294_912117

Comment: Please clarify what you’re trying to accomplish.

Comment: @DanielB he was clearly asking where to place the GET query (he clearly didn't know, and wanted to know) and how to get an IP address of a website, and you shouldn't always assume that people are trying to ask something else. And some people may just ask something out of curiosity to understand something. And that answer can give them knowledge that helps them in accomplishing other things in the future, for example from my answer, Marty now sees that he can do nc on his raspberry pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the IP of a website domain e.g. www.google.com   just open a cmd prompt(start....cmd) and do `ping www.google.com<ENTER>`

so the IP for www.google.com is 74.125.24.104

```
C:\>ping www.google.com

Pinging www.google.com [74.125.24.104] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 74.125.24.104: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=50

Ping statistics for 74.125.24.104:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 28ms, Maximum = 28ms, Average = 28ms
Control-C
^C
C:\>
```

The thing you describe will get the html of the webpage returned at a command prompt. You need to make a raw connection to the http server That concept is  quite far beyond your knowledge though if you thought an HTTP request would get an IP. And making an HTTP request is not relevant to getting an IP.

But on that subject of making an HTTP request (which is what that GET command is doing), there is a program called telnet that comes with Windows.. but people don't tend to use it much.. and it might only do the telnet protocol, and not do raw. People tend to use alternatives like Putty.  Using nc in cygwin is an alternative

You can download cygwin and then you may have to download the nc package, then use the 'nc' command.. I must say i'm not having great success getting the page, but this is the idea.

```
$ nc www.htmlgoodies.com 80
GET HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Server: AkamaiGHost
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 216
Expires: Thu, 21 May 2015 17:07:01 GMT
Date: Thu, 21 May 2015 17:07:01 GMT
Connection: close

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;7&#46;9557dd58&#46;1432228021&#46;0
</BODY>
</HTML>

$
```

or slightly better

```
$ nc www.htmlgoodies.com 80
GET / HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Server: AkamaiGHost
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 192
Expires: Thu, 21 May 2015 17:07:41 GMT
Date: Thu, 21 May 2015 17:07:41 GMT
Connection: close

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Invalid URL</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Invalid URL</H1>
The requested URL "&#47;", is invalid.<p>
Reference&#32;&#35;9&#46;9557dd58&#46;1432228061&#46;4ae720
</BODY></HTML>

$
```

better yet

```
$ nc htmlgoodies.com 80
GET / HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 21 May 2015 19:56:53 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Apr 2012 05:29:47 GMT
ETag: "9b-4bd74a4e268c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 155
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: public
Cache-Control: public
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<html>
<center><br><img src="construction.jpg"><br><img src="note.jpg"></center>
<!-- PRODUCTION WEB is alive -->
<!-- PRODUCTION WEB is alive -->
</html>

$
```

you can use wireshark to figure out how a request should look.

it doesn't work on google, that might be 'cos google is only https, and doing https is a bit trickier.

Anyhow, making an HTTP request even if you get it right, won't show you the IP.

A DNS lookup will, and Ping will cause that to be made and show the IP.

Comment: Thanks a million.  Actually realized I could do this from my RaspberryPi.  I'm a real Linux novice so did not know of the nc command.  I tried it and figured out how to add the GET command to it. Worked great

Comment: @Marty glad to be able to answer it. you can accept this answer by clicking the tick next to it